# Proving the equivalency between 2 identities

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to prove that these two identities are equivalent:

$A\cap(B\oplus C) = (A \cup B) \oplus (A \cup C)$

and

$B = C$

I am very confused on the methods of solving proofs, and since this problem has equivalent expressions used to prove a separate equivalency I am completely lost. How would I go about solving this (It's not a homework/test problem, I am just confused on how to solve these kinds of proofs). I understand I am suppose to include the work I have already done on the problem, but I have no idea how to even start.

Answer (score 0):

You are asked to show that $B=C$ **if and only if** $A\cap (B\oplus C) = (A\cup B) \oplus (A\cup C)$. As you correctly noted, this requires an *equivalence* proof, i.e. one that goes in both directions. More often than not, one direction is significantly easier than the other one (we usually call it *trivial*). This happens to be the case with the problem in question:

$(\Rightarrow )$ Suppose $B=C$. Rewrite the second identity as $A\cap (B\oplus B) = (A\cup B) \oplus (A\cup B)$. But since  $X\oplus X = \emptyset$ for any set $X$ (draw a Venn diagram if you don't understand why), we get $$A\cap (B\oplus B) = \emptyset = (A\cup B) \oplus (A\cup B).$$ 
Now we prove $(\Leftarrow )$, which is a little bit more involved:

Suppose $A\cap (B\oplus C) = (A\cup B) \oplus (A\cup C)$. Since the definition of $\oplus$ exludes intersections, we know that for any $a\in A$, $a\notin (A\cup B)\oplus (A\cup C)$. This implies that $a\notin A\cap (B\oplus C)$, hence it is empty. Therefore $(A\cup B) \oplus (A\cup C)$ is empty too, but it is a basic property of $\oplus$ that $X\oplus Y = \emptyset$ iff $X=Y$, so we finally conclude $B=C$, as required.

Thus we have indeed verified both directions of the proof.